# Defining Performing Questions

Tags: discussion

Recently we had questions about certain aspects of performing such as [DMX lighting](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15034/sending-dmx-from-midi-any-suggestions-experience) and [mp3s](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15690/how-can-i-detect-corrupt-incomplete-mp3-files). I personally feel like they are off-topic because they don't really reflect the live music aspect of performing, but I would like to know where the community stands on this and if we need to broaden or limit our scope for performing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site is about making music.

There are lots of different aspects to making music, and, in general, questions are on topic as long as they are directly related to making music.

Let's look at [the FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Musical Practice and Performance Stack Exchange is for musicians,
>   students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question about...
>
> ```
> practice & performance technique
> music theory and notation, history, or composition
> instrument maintenance
> usage of specific music software
> ```
>
> and it is not about...
>
> ```
> identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.
> shopping, product or music search, or buying/selling recommendations
> audio production techniques and equipment
> listening recommendations or recommendations of pieces to play
> requesting a list of resources
> legal issues
> ```
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Our site is called "Musical Practice and Performance," but there is a lot that goes into putting on a concert, and we only answer questions here that are directly related to making music.

Questions about a performance are only on-topic if they are from the musicians point of view.  So a question about playing an instrument is definitely on-topic, and a question about lighting is not.  Even though lighting can be an important part of a performance, we only answer questions about making music here.

Playing recorded music can be a gray area.  We have questions tagged [dj](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dj).  However, those questions are not about a DJ in the sense of a radio or wedding DJ, playing complete songs, but rather a DJ that mixes and combines recorded sounds in a new way to make new live music.  One is making music, the other is simply playing back previously recorded music.  We only allow the questions about making music.

For questions that deal with the other aspects of a musical performance, there are other sites:

- [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) for questions about live audio and recording equipment and techniques.
- [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) for questions about video recording and video playback during a performance.
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) can help with general computer hardware and software questions for audio playback and other purposes not directly related to making music.

There are some proposed sites in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) that will also be useful if and when they launch:

- [Theatre](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53104/theatre?referrer=z_OiOxXD4_oyVElmt9PeEw2) might cover technical aspects, theatre management, and perhaps even ticket sales and promotion.
- [Entertainment Lighting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64009/entertainment-lighting?referrer=ujZCFTfJlnXA8jScE7Kc4Q2) specifically focuses on the lighting aspects of performance.